# Is it possible to add functions to getfenv(2) when both are modules?

Tags: lua

This is the desired effect:

```
-- in module: A
module(...)
require('B')

new_func('my_val') -- new_func is defined in "B"

-- in module: B
module(...)
getfenv(2).new_func = function () end  -- this does not work

-- this does
getfenv(2).A.new_func = function () end
```

This is more curiosity than for practical needs. I'm hoping to learn more of what `getfenv` does through this esoteric problem.

Since `getfenv(2)` is supposed to return an env, why doesn't `getfenv(2).new_func` work in the above example?

I also don't understand why `getfenv(1) from A ~= getfenv(2) in B`.

(I also want to avoid the use of `debug`, including [debug.setupvalue](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-debug.setupvalue))

Answer (score 1):

`module` sets the global environment to a table named by its first argument. Therefore, anything defined in module "B" goes in the table called B, which is then installed in `package.loaded["B"]` when `require` runs. This is why in order to change the environment, you have to use the module name as an index into the table returned by `getfenv`.

You'll find this info [here](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ModulesTutorial) under "the old way".

Comment: Actually, I knew that `module` sets a table with the mod name in the global env. The part I seem to be getting wrong is that `require` evaluates the module code in different environments then what I expect.  So `getfenv` returns something I don't expect in the module B definition. If I used `getfenv` from within a module B function (and not in the module B definition), then everything works as I thought it would.

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that since you can [customize](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#6.3) the hell out of the way `require` works, it might not be a good idea (or future proof) to rely on specific environment manipulations it does.

Comment: Very true. That's why I plan on *not* using `getfenv` when `require` is doing it's business.

Comment: Plus they got rid of `getfenv` and `setfenv` in 5.2, I hear.

Comment: Right. `_ENV` and `_G` are put in. But, I tolerate 5.1 since it seems it will be around for some time.

Comment: It would be very nice if you could accept/upvote my answer if you think it's good enough. :)

Comment: My edit was rejected. It was considered to "radically different". So I will have to not accept this answer. The main problem was the `require` env. I'm sorry for the confusion. However, thank you for spending the time to answer.  I did upvote your other comments.

Comment: No problem, mate, as long as you gained the knowledge you needed from this question.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what the problem is: `require` does not do what I think it does:

```
-- in A.lua
require("b")

-- That is not the same as:
(function (mod_name)
  -- run B.lua
end)("b")
```

`require` runs chunks in the global environment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18311328/841803

Therefore, `getfenv(2)` will return `getfenv(0)` if used in the way in the opening question.

You have to use `getfenv` in a B function that is called by A:

```
-- module A
module(...)
require("b").import()
new_func("some val")

-- module B
module(...)

function new_func(val)
  print(val)
end

function import ()
  getfenv(2).new_func = new_func
end
```