# Is it ever documented that `require` runs chunks in the global env?

Tags: lua

When you write a module, the file is run in the global environment, not the calling environment:

```
-- other_file.lua
require('my_file')

-- my_file.lua
getfenv(2) == getfenv(0)   -- true
setfenv(1, {})             -- or module(...)
getfenv(2) == getfenv(0)   -- true
```

I don't ever remember reading about this. Is it mentioned/documented anywhere?

(This question is more about `require` rather than `getfenv`. I know it's removed in 5.2.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not explicitly documented but in the absence of any precise statement you should assume that it works like the rest of Lua, that is, using the global environment.

`dofile` also runs the file in the global environment, not in the calling environment. In other words, `dofile` is not the same as `include`, which Lua does not have.

`require` is essentially a version of `dofile` that supports paths and caches loaded files. So, it also runs the file in the global environment, not in the calling environment.